# iptables TPROXY gets hit but doesn't redirect to port

Tags: node.js, debian, ip, iptables, transparentproxy

I'm running `Debian 8` with `iptables`.

I have the following rule:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5000 -j TPROXY --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1 --on-port 4000
```

I simply want to redirect all traffic going with destination port 5000 to port 4000.

The standard `iptables` `REDIRECT` is not usable in my case, as it alters the packet and changes the original destination port.

Looking at `iptables -t mangle -nvL` I can see the rule being hit:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 5056 packets, 13M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   12   720 TPROXY     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5000 TPROXY redirect 0.0.0.0:4000 mark
 0x1/0x1
```

But my service running on port `4000` doesn't intercept the packets.

I have a simple `NodeJS` application listening for all `TCP` on port `4000`, which doesn't get any `packets`:

```
server.listen(4000, () => { console.log('listening on 4000'); });
```

Also, running `wireshark` on `TCP` port 4000 on all interfaces doesn't show anything.

Comment: I am stumbling across the same problem. Although my setup is exactly the same, I understand the solutions to this problem can be numerous. Nonetheless, your solution might help me. 

How did you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set up the routing rule:

```
# 1 is --tproxy-mark parameter in iptables command
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 100
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
```